# Render-on-Demand Three.js multiple canvases (with class implementation)

Tags: javascript, three.js

My case is like this: I have an asset inventory with multiple assets and I want whenever the user hovers on top of them to start the rendering with an OrbitController (I would prefer Trackball but I know that it is not possible due to a bug). The point is that the "this" variable of the class instance can not pass into the render method of the class  :

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';



class Main {

  constructor(canvasId)
  {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(canvasId);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: this.canvas});

    this.fov = 75;
    this.aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
    this.near = 0.1;
    this.far = 5;
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(this.fov, this.aspect, this.near, this.far);
    this.camera.position.z = 2;

    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.canvas);
    this.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    this.controls.update();

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();


    this.color = 0xFFFFFF;
    this.intensity = 1;
    this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(this.color, this.intensity);
    this.light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    this.scene.add(this.light);


    this.boxWidth = 1;
    this.boxHeight = 1;
    this.boxDepth = 1;
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(this.boxWidth, this.boxHeight, this.boxDepth);
  }

  makeInstance(geometry, color, x){

    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(color);

    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(cube);
    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

   
  resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    this.canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
    let width = this.canvas.clientWidth;
    let height = this.canvas.clientHeight;
    let needResize = this.canvas.width !== width || this.canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }

    return needResize;
  }

  render() {
    
    // this -> control object or window whereas it should be the class instance   
    if (this.resizeRendererToDisplaySize(this.renderer)) {
      this.canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
      this.camera.aspect = this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    
  }

  starter() {

    this.makeInstance(this.geometry, 0x44aa88,  0);
    this.makeInstance(this.geometry, 0x8844aa, -2);
    this.makeInstance(this.geometry, 0xaa8844,  2);

    this.render();

    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.render);

    // note: this is a workaround for an OrbitControls issue
    // in an iframe. Will remove once the issue is fixed in
    // three.js

    window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.focus();
    });

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}



let main = new Main('#a');
main.starter();
```

The only thing that I could do to work (but not correctly) is to replace "this" inside the render method with the "main" instance

```js
render() {
        
           
    if (main.resizeRendererToDisplaySize(this.renderer)) {
      main.canvas = main.renderer.domElement;
      main.camera.aspect = main.canvas.clientWidth / main.canvas.clientHeight;
      main.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    main.renderer.render(main.scene, main.camera);
    
}
```

However in this manner I kill the class, and I am not able to generate other instances e.g. main2
I have generate a codepen: https://codepen.io/jimver04/pen/XWjLPLo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing `this.render` to the event handlers. `this.render` is technically a pointer to the prototype function (`Main.prototype.render`).

When the handler is fired, the context will be dependent on how the origin executes the handler. In most cases, the context given to the handler will be that of the origin (or possibly even `null`). For example, `window.addEventListener( 'resize', handler );` will fire resize events by calling the equivalent of `handler.call( window, event );`

There are a couple ways to get around this.

### Arrow Functions implicit `this`

Arrow functions use the `this` of the context in which they are defined. So if your arrow function is defined in a member function of your class, and that member function is being executed within a context of an instance of that class, then `this` within the body of that arrow function will reference the instance.

```js
class Test{

  constructor(){

    this.name = "Test"

    // Arrow function defined within the context of an instance:
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', () => {
      console.log( this.name ) // prints: "Test"
    } )

    // Normal function will execute with "window" as its "this"
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {
      console.log( this.name ) // results may vary based on your browser, but "this" is not an instance of Test
    } )

  }

}
```

### Binding a function to a context

Using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) can attach a function to a specified context. The `bind` function returns a new function permanently bound to the provided context.

```js
class Test{

  constructor(){

    this.name = "Test"

    this.boundRender = this.render.bind( this ) // returns "render" bound permanently to "this"

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.boundRender )

  }

  render(){
    console.log( this.name )
  }

}
```

The example above will still print "Test" to the console. Even though the `resize` event wants to execute the handler with the `window` context, the `bind` has overridden that and locked the handler to executing within the context of the instance to which it was bound.

Comment: I have used arrows separetely and both for :   this.controls.addEventListener('change', () => {this.render} );

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {this.render});     However, nothing happens.

Comment: However, the "Bind" solution seems to work. The critical point is to bind it in the constructor! Thanks bro, I have updated the codepen with the correct solution using bind: https://codepen.io/jimver04/pen/XWjLPLo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TheJim01 !  Below is the final solution with **bind** methodology that works (the solution with arrows does not work). Also can be found analytically in https://codepen.io/jimver04/pen/XWjLPLo

```
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';



class Main {

  constructor(canvasId)
  {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(canvasId);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: this.canvas});

    this.fov = 75;
    this.aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
    this.near = 0.1;
    this.far = 5;
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(this.fov, this.aspect, this.near, this.far);
    this.camera.position.z = 2;

    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.canvas);
    this.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    this.controls.update();

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();


    this.color = 0xFFFFFF;
    this.intensity = 1;
    this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(this.color, this.intensity);
    this.light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    this.scene.add(this.light);


    this.boxWidth = 1;
    this.boxHeight = 1;
    this.boxDepth = 1;
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(this.boxWidth, this.boxHeight, this.boxDepth);
    
     this.boundRender = this.render.bind( this );
  }

  makeInstance(geometry, color, x){

    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(color);

    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(cube);
    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }



  resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    this.canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
    let width = this.canvas.clientWidth;
    let height = this.canvas.clientHeight;
    let needResize = this.canvas.width !== width || this.canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }

    return needResize;
  }

  render() {
    
    if (this.resizeRendererToDisplaySize(this.renderer)) {
      this.canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
      this.camera.aspect = this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    
  }

  starter() {

    this.makeInstance(this.geometry, 0x44aa88,  0);
    this.makeInstance(this.geometry, 0x8844aa, -2);
    this.makeInstance(this.geometry, 0xaa8844,  2);

    this.render();

    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.boundRender );

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.boundRender);

    // note: this is a workaround for an OrbitControls issue
    // in an iframe. Will remove once the issue is fixed in
    // three.js

    window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.focus();
    });

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}



let main = new Main('#a');
main.starter();

let main2 = new Main('#b');
main2.starter();
```